# Batch file closes before completing all lines

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I'm using a batch file to run a few scripts in a row.

The batch file is as follows

```
rawler http://example.com > results.txt
ruby parse.rb
notepad results2.txt
```

After completeing the first line, the Command Prompt closes itself.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

*EDIT*

Rawler is a ruby gem

Comment: Under which shell on which OS is this running? Is there a way to see the return status from the first command?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 using the default command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `rawler` a batch file, maybe? In that case you need to prepend `call`:

```
call rawler http://example.com > results.txt
```

Comment: rawler is not a batch file, it's a Ruby Gem, the code is within the batch file called check-links.bat, I'm calling it by double clicking it.

Comment: I have no idea how a ruby gem would execute on its own on Windows. Could you somehow figure out how exactly it is run? Maybe the gem is associated with a batch file which causes this behaviour, then.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused? I thought I could just write Command Prompt Code within the .bat file and have it run when I double click on the .bat

Comment: Yes, but batch files behave differently from the interactive console in some cases. This includes calling other batch files (and variable handling in `for`).

Comment: @PhilipK: Even if RubyGems are not batch files themselves, they must have something in common with the latter, as [this guy](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/168526 "installing gems in a batch file") apparently benefited from the advice to put the `call` command in front of invocation of a RubyGem.

Comment: I'm trying to run a node/coffeescript application via a .bat file and when I add call in front of my coffee commands, the command line says "call: command not found", any ideas?